# Behaviour of QMetaObject within a base class constructor

Tags: qt

I have a simple QObject-derived object:

```
class MyObject : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyObject(QObject* parent = 0);
};

MyObject::MyObject(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent) {
    std::cout<<"[BASE] "<<this->metaObject()->className()<<std::endl;
}
```

And I further derive this object:

```
class MyDerivedObject : public MyObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyDerivedObject(QObject* parent);
};

MyDerivedObject::MyDerivedObject(QObject* parent) : MyObject(parent) {
    std::cout<<"[DERIVED] "<<this->metaObject()->className()<<std::endl;
}
```

Whenever I instantiate this class, I get the following output:

```
MyDerivedObject y;

## OUTPUT ###
[BASE] MyObject
[DERIVED] MyDerivedObject
```

I don't get it. Since the inheritance hierarchy is `MyDerivedObject` -> `MyObject` -> QObject, they both have the same instance of a **QObject** as a parent (right?). I know that most of the Run-time type information is provided via the **moc**, but that shouldn't change the fact that once I do a `static_cast<QObject*>(/*MySomeObject*/)` on a pointer to one of those objects, they are the same thing (even in memory) as long as the QObject functionality is concerned. Then why do I get different return values of `className()`? Either ways, how do I obtain the name of the type the QObject actually is of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the details but each QObject-derived class has it own copy of meta object structure:

```
MyDerivedObject y;

qDebug() << (void*) y.metaObject();
qDebug() << (void*) y.MyObject::metaObject();
```

That gets you 2 different pointers to meta object.

Edit: I am not sure what your second question is. But if you want to know if a QObject is derived from a given class name, use [QObject::inherits()](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qobject.html#inherits) to find out.

Comment: My second question was more like, "When the base-class constructor is called, then within the scope of the base-class constructor, how do I find out the `className` of the derived-class that invoked in the first place". Your answer did help me in understanding the issue and developing a workaround. As for my question, now that I see it, it doesn't really seem possible. Thanks a lot :)